# How to load shared library created in Matlab

Tags: matlab, modelica, openmodelica

I tried to create an OpenModelica model with liquid flow and Media.
And I have a function in Matlab that calculates the PDE (partial differential equation) in pdetool.
I would like to create a shared dynamic library (.so file) in Matlab by MCR and load it in the model.
My platform: OpenModelica used on Linux or Mac OS.  MCR on Linux and Mac OS installed.

In Matlab I can generate only DLL (may be it's possible to generate libmyfunc.so?).

When I try to compile the model with extern C function I got an error:

```
#omc +s test_matlab_so.mo func_mathlab.mo
#make -f test_matlab_so.makefile
/usr/bin/clang -Wimplicit-function-declaration   -O0 -falign-functions -march=native     -I"/opt/openmodelica/include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME  -c -o test_matlab_so_functions.o test_matlab_so_functions.c
clang: warning: optimization flag '-falign-functions' is not supported
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-falign-functions'
In file included from test_matlab_so_functions.c:7:
In file included from ./test_matlab_so_includes.h:4:
./shared_train/src/lib_summ.c:90:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'GetModuleFileName' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (!GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("lib_summ"), path_to_dll, _MAX_PATH))
       ^
./shared_train/src/lib_summ.c:90:26: warning: implicit declaration of function 'GetModuleHandle' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (!GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("lib_summ"), path_to_dll, _MAX_PATH))
                         ^
./shared_train/src/lib_summ.c:90:55: error: use of undeclared identifier 'path_to_dll'
  if (!GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("lib_summ"), path_to_dll, _MAX_PATH))
                                                      ^
./shared_train/src/lib_summ.c:90:68: error: use of undeclared identifier '_MAX_PATH'
  if (!GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("lib_summ"), path_to_dll, _MAX_PATH))
                                                                   ^
./shared_train/src/lib_summ.c:94:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'path_to_dll'
            mclGetEmbeddedCtfStream(path_to_dll);
                                    ^
test_matlab_so_functions.c:19:16: warning: implicit declaration of function '_mlfSumm' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  _v_out_ext = _mlfSumm(_v_a_ext, _v_b_ext);
               ^
3 warnings and 3 errors generated.
make: *** [test_matlab_so_functions.o] Error 1
```

Can someone help me with integrating OpenModelica and Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with Linux but I did the same thing in Windows using MCR. Check this out:
http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94471-how-do-i-create-a-c-c-shared-library-with-matlab-compiler-that-can-be-used-in-a-microsoft-visual-c

When you do this, you will get a DLL as well as a static library. You need to copy both of them into the folder that your modelica code is located at and then set the library in the "Library" attibute of your modelica function which calls the external function.

Keep in mind that if you are using a 64 or 32 bit dymola, you are supposed to create the DLL using the same version of matlab correspondingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According Matlab document and OpenModelica documentation about usage of extern C functions I need to do 1) create shared lib in Matlab. 2) Write simple c wrapper for initialisation of MCR routine and call my shared lib. 3) Call my C wrapper from OpenModelica. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I created two shared libraries one from my matlab file and the other one from the c wrapper which I then used in Dymola.

Comment: I thank you! We did it, but got the next problem: load dll on Linux ;)

Comment: What compiler are you building with? Have you tried building with gcc/g++?

Comment: Matlab uses MS Visual Studio

Comment: You cannot load a dll on Linux unless you use wine. The Linux version of Matlab should be able to generate shared objects. Check with the file command what the files actually are (it could be a shared object with a .dll extension). You can link in shared objects using dlopen in C or the Modelica Library annotation in OpenModelica.

Comment: The linux versions of matlab support gcc as mentioned [here](http://de.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/index.html?sec=glnxa64).  I guess you will then get a *.o fie which you can use in the external function call just like the DLL:  `annotation (Library="Mylib.o")`